# How do I write a test class/test method for a controller?

Tags: unit-test

As I'm new to SFDC, I've recently written a basic controllers for visualforce pages, and now need to test them. Problem is I don't know how to test the thing. can someone help me get started?.

```
public class contact_list_controller {

    public String user_contact_EmailID ='chandan@gmail.com';
    public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    public List<Case> cases{get;set;}
    public Case detailsCase{get;set;}
    public Contact contact_case {get; set;}
    public Case newcases {get; set;}
    public Case CommentCase{get;set;}
    public CaseComment case_comment {get; set;}
    public boolean displayPopup {get; set;} 
    public boolean case_comment_popup {get; set;}
    public String Case_ID;

    public contact_list_controller()
    {
    contact_case = new Contact();
    newcases = new Case();
    detailscase = new Case();
    case_comment = new CaseComment();
    try{
       contacts=[Select ID,name,phone,mobilephone,fax,email,birthdate,mailingcity,mailingstate,mailingcountry,homephone from contact where email = :user_contact_EmailID];
       cases=[Select casenumber ,Description,isclosed, isdeleted,priority,status,subject,type,reason,origin,CreatedDate from Case where case.contactid IN (Select ID from contact where email = :user_contact_EmailID) ORDER BY casenumber DESC limit 10];
      }
       catch (Exception ex) {
                          System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'contact_list_controller.save() Exception: ' + ex);
          }
    }
    //Function which save's the new case
     public void Save() {        
         try{
            contact_case = [select Id from contact where email =:user_contact_EmailID];         
            newcases.contactid = contact_case.Id;
            insert newcases;
            displayPopup = false;
        }
       catch (Exception ex) {
                          System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'contact_list_controller.save() Exception: ' + ex);
          }
      finally{
              newcases = new Case();
             }    
        }
    // function to close the popup    
    public void ClosePopup(){
         displayPopup=false;
    } 
    //function to close casecomment
    public void Casecomment_close(){
            case_comment_popup = false;
    }

    // function to show the popup    
    public void showPopup() {        
        displayPopup = true;     
    }      

    public void case_detail(){
        try{
        Case_ID = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myParam');
        detailscase=[select casenumber,Description,isclosed, isdeleted,priority,status,subject,type,reason,origin,CreatedDate from case where casenumber= :Case_ID];
        displayPopup = true;
          }
       catch (Exception ex) {
                          System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'contact_list_controller.save() Exception: ' + ex);
          }
    }
    public void casecomment(){
         case_comment_popup = true;   
    }
    public void save_casecomment(){
          try{
              CommentCase = [Select ID,priority,origin,type,status,reason,subject,Description,isclosed from Case where casenumber= :Case_ID];
              if(CommentCase.ID!= null){
                  case_comment.parentid = CommentCase.Id;
                  insert case_comment;
                  case_comment_popup = false;
              }
          }
       catch (Exception ex) {
                          System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'contact_list_controller.save() Exception: ' + ex);
          }
      finally{
          case_comment = new CaseComment();
    }
  }   
}
```

and this is my apex page

```
<apex:page  showheader="false">
        <style>
         <!-- CSS for displaying detail and chat side by side -->
           #wr {margin: 0 auto;}
            #leftdetail, #rightchat { border: 1px solid white;float: left;min-height: 450px;color: white;margin-left:2%;}
            #leftdetail {margin-left:2%;min-width:70%;max-width:70%}
            #rightchat {width:25%;margin-right:2%}
       </style>
       <style type="text/css">
        .custPopup{
            background-color: white;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-style: solid;
            z-index: 9999;
            left: 50%;
            padding:10px;
            position: absolute;
            /* These are the 3 css properties you will need to change so the popup 
            displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set 
            margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can add 
            the height property for a fixed size pop up if you want.*/
            width: 600px;
            margin-left: -250px;
            top:100px;
        }
        .popupBackground{
            background-color:black;
            opacity: 0.20;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 9998;
        }

     </style> 

       <div id="wr">
            <div id="leftdetail">
       <!--Tab Panel -->  
       <c:Tabpanel >  
             <!--Contact Tab for getting the Contact details-->  
             <c:Tab title="Contact">  
                   <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Detail">  
              <apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="contact">
                    <table cellpadding="15">
                      <tr>
                          <td><apex:outputText value="Contact Name : {!contact.Name}"/> </td>
                      </tr>    
                      <tr>
                            <td><apex:outputText value="Phone : {!contact.phone}"/></td>
                            <td><apex:outputText value="Email : {!contact.email}"/></td>
                            <td><apex:outputText value="Fax : {!contact.Fax}"/> </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td><apex:outputText value="Mobile : {!contact.Mobilephone}"/></td>
                          <td><apex:outputText value="Home Phone :{!contact.Homephone}"/></td>
                          <td><apex:outputText value="Birthdate : {!contact.Birthdate}"/></td>
                      </tr>    
                      <tr>
                          <td><apex:outputText value="City : {!contact.MailingCity}"/></td>
                          <td><apex:outputText value="State : {!contact.MailingState}"/></td> 
                          <td><apex:outputText value="Country : {!contact.MailingCountry}"/></td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
            </apex:repeat>
       </apex:pageBlock> 
     </c:Tab>  
     <!--Case tab which contain the case details for the respective contact -->       
            <c:Tab title="Cases">
            <apex:form >  
              <apex:pageBlock title="Case Info"> 
                    <!-- Adding New case for the respective contact-->
                        <apex:commandButton value="New Case" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="tstpopup"/>
                               <apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup">
                                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
                                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"> 
                                                  <apex:pageBlock title="New Case">
                                                        <apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="contact">
                                                            <table cellpadding="15">
                                                                  <tr>
                                                                      <td><apex:outputText value="Contact Name : {!contact.Name}"/> </td>
                                                                  </tr> 
                                                             </table>
                                                        </apex:repeat>     
                                                  <apex:pageBlockSection >                                                      
                                                          <apex:inputField value="{!newcases.Priority}"  />
                                                          <apex:inputField value="{!newcases.Origin}" />
                                                          <apex:inputField value="{!newcases.Type}" />
                                                          <apex:inputField value="{!newcases.Status}" />                             
                                                          <apex:inputField value="{!newcases.reason}" />                                           
                                                          <apex:inputField value="{!newcases.subject}" />
                                                  </apex:PageBlockSection>
                                                  <apex:PageBlockSection >
                                                        <apex:inputField value="{!newcases.Description}" style="width:450px"/>
                                                  </apex:pageBlockSection>                                                      
                                                  </apex:pageBlock>                     
                                            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="tstpopup"/>
                                            <!--saving the New case Detail -->
                                            <apex:CommandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" rerender="tstpopup"/>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
             <!-- to display the list of cases for the respective contact-->               
                  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="case">                                                 
                                <apex:column headerValue="Case Number">
                                <!-- onclick CaseID it will display the respective case detail-->
                                         <apex:commandLink action="{!case_detail}" rerender="case_detai"> {!case.casenumber}
                                                 <apex:param name="myParam" value="{!case.casenumber}"/>
                                         </apex:commandLink>
                                             <apex:outputPanel id="case_detai">
                                                 <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
                                                 <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">  
                                                         <apex:PageBlock title="Case detail">
                                                               <apex:repeat value="{!detailscase}" var="detailscases">
                                                                       <apex:PageBlock title="Subject:{!detailscases.subject}" >

                                                                        <table cellpadding="20">
                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                   <td><apex:outputText value="Case ID : {!detailscases.casenumber}"/> </td>
                                                                                   <td><apex:outputText value="Case Status:{!detailscases.status}"/>  </td>
                                                                                   <td><apex:outputText value="Priority :{!detailscases.priority}"/> </td>
                                                                                   <td><apex:outputText value="Case Origin :{!detailscases.origin}"/> </td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                  <td><apex:outputText value="Created:{!detailscases.isclosed}"/> </td>
                                                                                  <td><apex:outputText value="Type:{!detailscases.type}"/> </td>
                                                                                  <td><apex:outputText value="Case Reason:{!detailscases.reason}"/></td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                              <tr>    
                                                                                  <td><apex:outputText value="Description: {!detailscases.Description}"/></td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                        </table>                        
                                                                     </apex:PageBlock> 
                                                                </apex:repeat>
                                                         </apex:PageBlock>      
                                                         <!-- for cancel/close the casedetail popup-->
                                                          <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" immediate="true" rerender="case_detai"/>
                                                               <apex:commandButton value="Case Comments" action="{!casecomment}" immediate="true" rerender="case_comment"/>
                                                                     <apex:outputPanel id="case_comment">
                                                                         <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!case_comment_popup}"/>
                                                                            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!case_comment_popup}"> 
                                                                               <apex:pageBlock title=" Case Comment">
                                                                                 <apex:repeat value="{!detailscase}" var="detailscases">
                                                                                 <table>
                                                                                       <tr>
                                                                                       <td><apex:outputText value="case ID:{!detailscases.casenumber}"/></td>
                                                                                       </tr>
                                                                                       <tr>                                                                                                
                                                                                       <td><apex:inputField value="{!case_comment.commentbody}" style="width:550px"/> </td>
                                                                                       </tr> 
                                                                                 </table>                                            
                                                                                       <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Casecomment_close}" rerender="case_comment"/>
                                                                                       <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save_casecomment}" rerender="case_comment"/> 
                                                                                         <apex:param name="comment_case_number" value="{!detailscases.casenumber}"/>  
                                                                                 </apex:repeat>                                   
                                                                               </apex:pageBlock>                                                                       
                                                                            </apex:outputPanel>
                                                                     </apex:outputPanel> 

                                                  </apex:outputPanel>
                                              </apex:outputPanel>
                                </apex:column>
                        <apex:column value="{!case.Subject}"/>                                           
                        <apex:column value="{!case.type}"/>   
                        <apex:column value="{!case.status}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!case.priority}"/> 
                        <apex:column value="{!case.Origin}"/> 
                        <apex:column value="{!case.CreatedDate}"/> 
                        <apex:column value="{!case.isclosed}"/>                            
                        <apex:column value="{!case.reason}"/>                                                   
                  </apex:pageBlockTable> 
          </apex:pageBlock>
          </apex:form>            
     </c:Tab>
     <c:Tab title="Device">    
            <apex:pageBlock title="Device Info">  
              <apex:repeat value="{!cases}" var="case">
                    <table cellpadding="10">                  
                  </table>
             </apex:repeat>
       </apex:pageBlock>  
     </c:Tab> 
     <c:Tab title="Chat Detail">
         <apex:pageBlock title="Chat detail">
         </apex:pageBlock>
     </c:Tab>
   </c:Tabpanel>
               </div>            
            <div id="rightchat">         
            </div>

            </div> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please correct your formatting. Also, try to read some SFDC beginners books or some more general programming articles about unit testing. It will solve your problem for sure.

Comment: Hello, @BartJuriewicz formatting means do I made any mistake in Controller...?

Comment: I mean to mark code as code. E.g. the first line of your code is visible as a plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Go through these links. It may help you.

1. http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/apex/faq-writing-test-class-in-salesforce/#Q2
2. http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm